# Syntax Error- SQL Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I will appreciate nay help I am new to SQL and I am using Microsoft Access. I wrote this myself so if something looks wrong, please let me know!

Also if you could answer this question, I have to write and run a SQL query to list all occurrences of a certain course.How do I begin going about doing this? I cannot locate anything on it in my book.

```
CREATE  TABLE CUSTOMER (
     CustomerNumber    Int PRIMARY KEY,
     CustomerLastName  Char (25)    NOT NULL,
     CustomerFirstName Char (25)    NOT NULL,
     Phone             Char (12)   NULL
);

CREATE  TABLE COURSE (
    CourseNumber Int PRIMARY KEY,
    Course       Char ( 15) NOT NULL,
    CourseDate   DateTime NOT NULL,
    Fee          Currency NOT NULL
);

CREATE  TABLE ENROLLMENT (
    CustomerNumber Int PRIMARY KEY,
    CourseNumber   Int NOT NULL,           
    AmountPaid     Currency NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `primary key`.  To answer your other question, look at using `where`...

Comment: `"I cannot locate anything on it in my book"` - I'm not sure what book you're using to learn SQL and/or Access, but if it doesn't cover *querying data* (selecting data) then it doesn't sound like the right book.

Comment: It does not contain anything about syntax errors, I have asked my professor for help but it is useless. I added the , after primary key it moved to the second table and says syntax error still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your queries on MS Acces 2007 and MS Access 2010 and works fine,

You should run each query at a time, not all at once, when I try to execute the entire SQL I get the same error message.

SQL1:

```
CREATE  TABLE CUSTOMER (
     CustomerNumber    Int PRIMARY KEY,
     CustomerLastName  Char (25)    NOT NULL,
     CustomerFirstName Char (25)    NOT NULL,
     Phone             Char (12)   NULL
);
```

SQL2:

```
CREATE  TABLE COURSE (
    CourseNumber Int PRIMARY KEY,
    Course       Char ( 15) NOT NULL,
    CourseDate   DateTime NOT NULL,
    Fee          Currency NOT NULL
);
```

SQL3:

```
CREATE  TABLE ENROLLMENT (
    CustomerNumber Int PRIMARY KEY,
    CourseNumber   Int NOT NULL,           
    AmountPaid     Currency NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did run it individually and worked out the kinks. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Few comments that may help you, first check the valid data types in MS-Access in your current version, for example: [MSDN-MS-Access DataTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx). You will see that Char and Int are not valid, also Numeric does not take arguments (you probably wanted to use Dobule). Also you are missing a comma (,) after the PRIMARY KEY in the first CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER statement. It may be a good practice using the GUI interface to create tables then move into DDL later.

Comment: Thank you I wanted currency actually your link helped. However I am still getting a syntax error in my second Create table?

Comment: 3 things, write (15) not ( 15) and tell us the exact error message. Alos run each create statement separately not as a group. It is easier to spot errors this way. I assume you fixed the 'int'.

Comment: Also, it may not be a good idea to name the column and the table with the same name. Table Course has a column named Course - This may be confusing even if the syntax allows it.

Comment: I fixed the 15 and changed the name from course to class it still is not working. the error message states "syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement"